# DensityPlot Increase Information

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

I am trying to make a density plot in Mathematica, however the distribution of the plot is not as visible as I would like. I plotted the same function in python and it contains a greater visible range of information. This can be seen in the first picture below.

[image]

When I try the same plot in Mathematica some information is lost. I cant see the decrease in intensity on either side of the central bright spot. I am using PlotRange "All" and I can adjust the plot range but I get large white spots where I am outside of the plot range.
I am not sure how to tackle the problem if anyone has any ideas I would appreciate your thoughts!

My code is as follows

```
DensityPlot[di, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All]
```

Thanks,
Ben
[image]

Comment: Have you tried increasing the plot range, like `DensityPlot[di, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}]`? Also could you give the explicit expression of `di`?

Comment: Without the definition of `di` we can't help you much. You can try using different color functions. The two darker spots on the left and right from your reference image can actually be seen as more reddish spots in your mathematica plot. If you want to replicate the `jet` color scheme you can generate it with code from [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753508/custom-colorfunction-colordata-in-arrayplot-and-similar-functions/9321152#9321152) and then use it with `ColorFunction->jet`.

Comment: Here is the entire code. In creasing the plot range does not reduce the effect but thanks for the suggestion.
 `z = 100;
r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2];
theta = ArcCos[z/r];
phi = ArcTan[y/x];
gama = 40;
beta = Sqrt[1 - (1/(gama^2))]
di = ((Sin[phi]^2) + ((Cos[theta] - beta)^2*
       Cos[phi]^2)/(1 - beta*Cos[theta])^2)/((1 - beta*Cos[theta])^3*
    gama^4)`

Comment: I dont see how knowing di could help, it could be any function, I believe solving the issue lies in plotting.

Comment: I suppose it's because `DensityPlot` is working correctly, and for it to be adjusted the way you want it, it would be helpful to have the actual function.  To get the sort of lines in your objective image, consider `ContourPlot`.  You also might construct a custom [`ColorFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorFunction.html).

Answer (score 5):

As said in the comments, you can use a different [`ColorFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorFunction.html), or you can rescale the data used to calculate the color function, or you can use [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ContourPlot.html) instead.
Here is an example of using a different `ColorFunction` and rescaling the data:

```
jet[u_?NumericQ] := 
 Blend[{{0, RGBColor[0, 0, 9/16]}, {1/9, Blue}, {23/63, Cyan}, {13/21,
      Yellow}, {47/63, Orange}, {55/63, Red}, {1, 
     RGBColor[1/2, 0, 0]}}, u] /; 0 <= u <= 1

DensityPlot[di, {x, -15, 15}, {y, -12, 12}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, ColorFunction -> (jet[(#)^.4] &), 
 PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 24/30, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image: density plot]

And here it is using rescaled data with `ContourPlot`:

```
ContourPlot[di, {x, -15, 15}, {y, -12, 12}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, ColorFunction -> (jet[(#)^.4] &), 
 PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 24/30, ImageSize -> 600, 
 Contours -> Table[x^(1/.7), {x, 0, 12500^.7, 5}], 
 ContourStyle -> None]
```

[image: contour plot]

Answer (score 1):

I used the jet function scaling linked to by Shrx above. There are many parameters to adjust to make the resolution improve. This Manipulate shows the effect of changing few parameters.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Manipulate[

 DensityPlot[di, {x, -plotRange, plotRange}, {y, -plotRange, plotRange}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, 
  ColorFunction -> (jet[(#)^scale] &), PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
    PlotPoints -> plotPoints, MaxRecursion -> maxRecursion, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> True, Mesh -> False, ClippingStyle -> Automatic, 
    ImageSize -> 600],

 {{scale, .5, "scale?"}, .1, 1, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{plotPoints, 50, "plotPoints?"}, 10, 300, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{maxRecursion, 10, "MaxRecursion?"}, 2, 14, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{plotRange, 5, "plot range?"}, 5, 15, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 ContinuousAction -> False,
 Initialization :>
  (
   z = 100; r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]; theta = ArcCos[z/r]; phi = ArcTan[y/x]; 
   gama = 40;
   beta = Sqrt[1 - (1/(gama^2))]; 
   di = ((Sin[phi]^2) + ((Cos[theta] - beta)^2*
     Cos[phi]^2)/(1 - beta*Cos[theta])^2)/((1 - beta*Cos[theta])^3*gama^4);
   jet[u_?NumericQ] := 
    Blend[{{0, RGBColor[0, 0, 9/16]}, {1/9, Blue}, {23/63, Cyan}, {13/21, Yellow}, 
      {47/63, Orange}, {55/63, Red}, {1, RGBColor[1/2, 0, 0]}}, u] /; 0 <= u <= 1
   )
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]